# Datamapper ORM- Codeigniter Advance Relationship

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datamapper

Please help me to understand the basic use of Datamapper's include_join_fields function. I tried it lots of but not getting any results.

I have application like [$object->include_join_fields()](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#include_join_fields)

I have User table and Country table.

Please help me to set $hasone=array('country_id'); relation

I haven't any idea about this all, even not getting the exact point after reading documentation of include_join_fields

Any help will appricate

Thanks

Comment: Please edit and provide question in format like in [this great article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

`include_join_fields` are for many to many relationships, where you have a `countries_users` pivot table, and users could belong to many country.

For example, you could take one `user`, and the `countries`, where he belongs to. But you also store, how is a `user` related to that `country`. You have to store this *extra field* in your pivot table: `countries_users`.

So your pivot table, `countries_users` will look like something like this, with an example extra field `is_he_working_there`:

```
id
country_id
user_id
is_he_working_there
```

When you make a query for the user's countries, Datamapper won't add that field default. And here comes the `include_join_field()`, so if you call that, Datamapper will add this field to the end result.

But with `hasone`, it won't take any effect, because you get the user, and the other table fields also. No pivot table here, so **don't need include_join_fields()**