# Datamapper (Codeigniter) JOIN table for MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datamapper

I am new to Datamapper. I want to learn how to use functions of datamapper for JOINing of tables.

It will be immense pleasure if anybody can provide me one live demo or standard offline example which shows the use of Datamapper include_related, has_one, has_many  relationship with Codeigniter Model/Controller in MySQL Database.

Please provide me a link or zip file including database table, so that i got the idea that where exactly i am doing mistake in learning standard practice of Datamapper.

Thank you

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic especially #4.

Comment: I had already asked question about this topic but till not get any proper answer, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866324/datamapper-orm-codeigniter-advance-relationship). Ultimately stackoverflow is aim to be made for people, by people to people.

Comment: "aim to be made for people, by people to people" true enough, and the people have said... "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**"

Comment: You won't beleive how powerfull is google: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/relationtypes.html